# Vuex modules - cannot set the ..mapGetters correvctly

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I currently defined my store structure as following

```
store
  modules
    User.js
 index.js
```

store/modules/User.js

```
import * as types from '@/store/mutation_types'
import firebase from 'firebase'

const state = {
  ...
  user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')) || null
}

const actions = {
  setUser ({commit}, newUser) {
    console.log('STORE ACTION setUser: ', newUser)
    commit(types.SET_USER, newUser)
  },
  signUserIn ({commit}, payload) {
    ...
  },
  signUserUp ({commit}, payload) {
    ...
  },
  logout: context => {
   ...
  }
}

const mutations = {
 ...
}

const getters = {
  ...
  user: state => state.user
}

export const User = {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  actions,
  mutations,
  getters
}
```

store/index.js

```
/**
 * Import Dependency
 */
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import { firebaseMutations } from 'vuexfire'
import * as types from '@/store/mutation_types'
import { User } from '@/store/modules/User.js'
import { Account } from '@/store/modules/Account.js'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  strict: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  state: {
    language: localStorage.getItem('language') || '',
    ...
  },
  actions: {
    switchLanguage ({ commit }, context) {
      commit(types.SET_LANGUAGE, context)
    },
    ...
  },
  getters: {
    language: state => state.language,
    sideNav: state => state.sideNav,
    showAssociation: state => state.showAssociation,
    ...
  },
  mutations: {
    ...
    },
    ...firebaseMutations
  },
  modules: {
    User,
    Account
  }
})

export default store
```

In a component , I need to use ..mapGetters from teh User module AND from the index.js

...mapGetters('User', ['user'], ['sideNav', 'showAssociation']),

BUT this is not right ...  I get an error :

```
 Property or method "showAssociation" is not defined
```

How should I write my ...mapGetters ?
or is it anything wrng in my User module ?

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to get getters from different modules, just map them seperately:

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters('User', ['user']),
  ...mapGetters(['showAssociation', 'sideNav'])
}
```